# Notepad++ regular expression <li>

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this line

```
"top/wedding", <li>Wedding 1924</li>
```

How I can replace what is inside the `<li>` by using a regular expression?

Comment: Calling Tony the Pony!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find what: `<li>.*</li>`

Replace with `<li>foo</li>`

search mode
`(*) regular expression`

[image: replace dialog window]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex in Notepad++.

Make sure "Regular expression" along with `.` matches newline is checked.

```
Find: <li>\K.*?(?=</li>)
Replace: something
```

Comment: This is the answer that could soothe Tony the Pony and save someone's career.

Comment: `^^^` Very correct. Not only soothe but caress as well.